# Probability question from GRE Quant

Tags: probability, solution-verification

The probability that Tom will win the Booker prize is $0.5$, and the probability that John will win the Booker prize is $0.4$. There is only Booker prize to win. What is the probability that at least on of them wins the prize?

Prossible answers: $\{0.2;\ 0.4;\ 0.7;\ 0.8;\ 0.9\}$

My solution: Let $T$ be the event that Tom will win the prize and $J$ is the event when John wins the prize. If we have one prize then $P(T\cap  J)=0$.
Hence $$P(T\cup  J)=P(T)+P(J)-P(T\cap  J)=0.5+0.4-0=0.9$$
However, $P(T^c)=1-0.5=0.5$ and $P(J^c)=1-0.4=0.6$. Then $$P(T\cup J)=1-P(T^c\cap J^c)=1-0.5\cdot 0.6=0.7.$$

We have two possible answers. Which one is the correct?
Please explain.

Comment: The first.  In the second you computed $P(T^c\cap J^c)$ incorrectly.

Comment: @lulu, Could you show please why my computation is incorrect?

Comment: You've incorrectly assumed $T^c$ and $J^c$ as independent

Comment: Yes I do know that. But why are they not independent?

Comment: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B\,|\,A)$.  Thus $P(T^c\cap J^c)=P(T^c)\times P(J^c\,|\,T^c)=.5\times .2 = .1$

Comment: Informally, knowing that $T$ did not get the prize dramatically increases the probability that $J$ did.  Take the extreme case wherein $T,J$ each have $\frac 12$ of winning.  In that case $T^c$ would imply $J$.  Your case is nearly the same as this.

Comment: I have done the same on the paper before you published that. But I have problems with calculating $P(J^c \mid T^c)$. How did you get that it is equal to 0.2?

Comment: You have told us that $T\cap J=\emptyset$.  Thus, of the $.5$ which comprise $T^c$, $.4$ of it is $J$.  It follows that $.1$, of that $.5$ must be the intersection $T^c\cap J^c$.   Thus the conditional probability is $\frac {.1}{.5}=.2$.

Comment: @lulu, Could you expand your answer please? I have some problems with understanding.

Comment: Try it this way:  model your problem by using a ten sided die, with faces $1-10$.  Let's say a roll of $1-5$ is a $T$ win, a roll of $6-9$ is a $J$ win and a roll of $10$ is a win for someone else.  You agree that this captures your situation, yes?  Now you can simply enumerate cases to verify the result.